# Получить посты группы ВК без токена

Tags: android, vkontakte-api

Как получить посты группы ВК без токена? Выходит, API не поможет. Как быть?

Comment: А почему вы считаете что токен обязателен? Он таки не обязателен вроде же

Comment: Сервисный ключ бери значит

Comment: Общедоступные посты спокойно получаются без ключей.

Comment: @br3t, любые действия с апи требуют токен, использую либу vk sdk с гитхаба

Comment: @Flippy где написано, что *любые* действия требуют токен? Сам придумал? ))

Comment: За андроид не буду говорить, не пользовал, но js-ом для сайта вполне себе тянется без ключа. Проверил curlом - тоже ок. Попробуйте например получить https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?owner_id=-36771297&v=5.60&count=10

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, да )

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что  надо читать мануалы  *facepalm* А там написано, что токен не обязателен

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Почитайте справку по работе с методом https://vk.com/dev/wall.get

Там в принципе все расписано:

> Этот метод можно вызвать с сервисным ключом доступа. Возвращаются только общедоступные данные.
>
> Этот метод можно вызвать с ключом доступа пользователя.

При этом там же говорится про сервисный ключ:

> Получить сервисный ключ доступа можно в настройках Вашего приложения. Ключ не привязан к IP-адресу при использовании с открытыми методами, срок его действия не ограничен. Если ключ был скомпрометирован, Вы можете сгенерировать новый ключ, при этом старый будет аннулирован.
>
> Сервисный ключ доступа идентифицирует Ваше приложение. Все запросы к API, совершённые с использованием Вашего ключа доступа, будут считаться совершёнными от имени Вашего приложения. Сервисный ключ доступа можно использовать только для запросов с серверной стороны приложения, его нельзя передавать и хранить на клиенте.

Comment: Емае. Извиняюсь, опять время потерял. Нет бы глянуть сайт апи я сам гадаю и придумываю что-то. Спасибо